# SAPUI5 - How to get expanded context from detail view

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to get context from expanded entity in a detail view but when I use expand parameter it only returns list of keys. I've tried using oModel.read with given keys in the list but without success.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
onInit : function () {
    var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
        busy : false,
        delay : 0,
        lineItemListTitle : this.getResourceBundle().getText("detailLineItemTableHeading")
    });

    this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);

    this.setModel(oViewModel, "detailView");

    this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded().then(this._onMetadataLoaded.bind(this));

},

_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
    var sObjectId =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectId;

    this.getModel("appView").setProperty("/layout", "TwoColumnsMidExpanded");
    this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then( function() {
        var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("Categories", {
            CategoryID :  sObjectId
        });
        this._bindView("/" + sObjectPath);
    }.bind(this));
},


_bindView : function (sObjectPath) {
    // Set busy indicator during view binding
    var oViewModel = this.getModel("detailView");

    oViewModel.setProperty("/busy", false);

        this.getView().bindElement({
        path : sObjectPath,
        parameters : {
            expand: "Products"
        },
        events: {
            change : this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
            dataRequested : function () {
                oViewModel.setProperty("/busy", true);
            },
            dataReceived: function () {
                oViewModel.setProperty("/busy", false);
            }
        }
    });
},

_onBindingChange : function () {
    var oView = this.getView(),
        oElementBinding = oView.getElementBinding();


    // No data for the binding
    if (!oElementBinding.getBoundContext()) {
        this.getRouter().getTargets().display("detailObjectNotFound");
        // if object could not be found, the selection in the master list
        // does not make sense anymore.
        this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.clearMasterListSelection();
        return;
    }

    var sPath = oElementBinding.getPath(),
        oResourceBundle = this.getResourceBundle(),
        oObject = oView.getModel().getObject(sPath),
        sObjectId = oObject.CategoryID,
        sObjectName = oObject.CategoryName,
        oViewModel = this.getModel("detailView"),
        oBindingContext = this.getView().getBindingContext().getObject();

        console.log("Object ", oObject);

    this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.selectAListItem(sPath);

        oViewModel.setProperty("/shareSendEmailSubject",
    oResourceBundle.getText("shareSendEmailObjectSubject", [sObjectId]));
    oViewModel.setProperty("/shareSendEmailMessage",
    oResourceBundle.getText("shareSendEmailObjectMessage", [sObjectName, sObjectId, location.href]));
},
```

And the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0RVv.png)

Expected output:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s1Yc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just how the ODataModel stores the Information.

If you read an EntitySet with an Expand Parameter it will request all this Data.
But in the Entity "Category(1)" it only stores the Reference/Path to the Product Entitys.

via. `this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/" + "Products(1)")` you access the Entity Object.

via. `this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/")` you can access all Entitys the Service Model requested incl. your Product Entitys.

What exactly do you wan't to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I thought I had tried this already but I must have misspelled something.